# loading xml in flash created from standard text tool with utf-8 chars

Tags: php, mysql, xml, actionscript-3, utf-8

**EDIT:**

found solution myself:

```
cityname = encodeURIComponent(cityname);
```

---

My flash has standard text field made by "Text Tool" and loads xml file generated from that field

```
function load_city_xml(cityname:String = ""):void {
city_list.removeAll();
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);

var urlstring:String = "http://example.com/xml_city.php?cityname="+ cityname;
trace(urlstring);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(urlstring));

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {

XML.ignoreWhitespace = true; 
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);

var i:Number;
for (i=0; i < xmlData.city.length(); i++) {

    city_list.addItem( {label:xmlData.city[i].namecity.text(),data:xmlData.city[i].id.text()});
    }

    }
}
load_city_xml();
```

xml has header

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>
```

and connection to the database is also as utf8

everything seems to work fine so far, it displays utf-8 chars correctly
problem exists if I do something like this:

```
load_city_xml(""+city_text_field.text);
```

it dosen't work if **text tool field** has special characters (like: ółśżźąćę), but works just fine for normal latin characters in textfield, it even displays data with special characters correctly.

generated link

> http://example.com/xml_city.php?cityname=ł

seems to not load any xml content, but if I type it in a browser it works fine, the xml data is displayed.

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
seems like php dosn't handle $_GET['cityname'] var from flash with special characters, but does from the browser